# How to convert Xcode project into workspace and avoid git merge conflicts

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

Currently I am working on a team project with Xcode that is stored in `Foo.xcodeproj`. We all work on our own branches and do git pull requests for merging into the common `dev` branch. I am at a point where I want to use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) and once I do a `pod install` then the workspace `Foo.xcworkspace` will be created. The CocoaPod docs say:

```
Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of 
the project file when building your project
```

On my branch I will have a workspace file whereas everyone else will be still working directly with the project file. I am trying to be preemptive and avoid difficult git merge conflicts. Will it matter if my teammates are still opening the project file or are we going to have merge conflict hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a one team you all should work in one either in Project or Workspace, are you the only one using `cocoapods` no one else in Team wants to get the functionalities available through `Pods`.
If you are the only one continuing with PODS be careful while committing the project file in git.

Answer to your question, just commit your `Podfile`, `podfile.lock` and `.xcworkspace` file in git and whenever the other teammate is getting the pull ask him to do a `pod install` and then open the `.xcworkspace` file to work as you did initially.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. The rest of the team will need CocoaPods to build once I am done. I have convinced everyone to get in there last commits by a given deadline and to only open the workspace after I am done. So I assume you don't commit the Pods/ directory e.g., put it the .gitignore -- it seems there are different opinions on this.

Comment: Committing Pods directory just make your repo heavy and increase the pull time, I generally don't commit that in repo. But varies developer to developer and project to project :) Also you can accept the answer of it is what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Just for your info cocoapods community highlighted the Pods repo commit pros and cons, you may wanna check- https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: I'll probably do what you suggest... i'll see what the opinions of the others are. it seems like i would be ok if someone merged work directly from a project, but better safe than spending time in merge conflict hell.